# best way to make base uiviewcontroller iphone

Tags: iphone

I an making an app which has many different uiviewcontrollers but they share the same functionality. I am going to make a basecontroller so the other classes extend this. However there are about 5-7 variables that I need to provide to the basecontroller. What is the proffered way to do this? Making a constructor that takes 7 parameters or is there better ways doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing will do the trick:

```
//different controllers that you want to implement
//it should subclass the base controller, as in this case, the SecondLevelViewContr
    @interface CheckListController : SecondLevelViewController {

//and remember to implement your base controller
    @interface SecondLevelViewController : UITableViewController {
```